# Is it possible to have multiple upsert operations in Postgres that are atomic?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, atomic, upsert

Similar to having multiple records inserted in one SQL statement, can multiple Upserts be executed atomically?

e.g

```
insert into students ("name","age") values ("sid",23) on conflict ("name") set "age"=12;
insert into students ("name","age") values ("jack",24) on conflict ("name") set "age"=14;
insert into students ("name","age") values ("tom",20) on conflict ("name") set "age"=13;
```

Comment: Why don't you use a single `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) following should work:

```
INSERT INTO students ("name", "age") VALUES ("sid", 23), ("jack",24), ("tom",20)
ON CONFLICT ("name") DO UPDATE SET "age" = EXCLUDED.age;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Surround with a begin and commit statements, like this:

```
begin;
insert into students ("name","age") values ("sid",23) on conflict ("name") do update set "age"=12;
insert into students ("name","age") values ("jack",24) on conflict ("name") do update set "age"=14;
insert into students ("name","age") values ("tom",20) on conflict ("name") do update set "age"=13;
commit;
```

These then constitute a transaction.  Some language drivers may have various ways of handling the begin and commit statements so please refer to your driver's documentation before proceeding if you are not just trying to use `psql`.

But there is no difference between an insert and an upsert in this regard.

Comment: The syntax is incorrect; it should be `ON CONFLICT (...) DO UPDATE SET`. I think the OP is looking for `VALUES (...), (...), ...`.

Comment: transactions are by nature atomic.  The whole thing succeeds or fails together.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, note he wants different values of the update age, which are in his example different from from the inserted value which seems strange to me.